# How to check if a string contains exactly 4 "non-letter, non-digit or non-space" in a row in C# regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to check if there are 4 symbols in a row in a string

For example

abcde/-*,f€gh

I want to match if there is /-*,

but the symbols can change to any non-letter, non-digit or non-space

Comment: Can you give an example of string and what you expect to match?

Comment: `/-*` is 3 characters, not `4`?

Comment: it is  4  with the comma

Comment: I actually defined it in the title @Cary Swoveland.

Comment: ard, I missed that. The font was too small.

Comment: Next time I will try to make it more readable. I know it is not an excuse but this one is my first question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't be disheartened, Arda, practice makes perfect.

Comment: If you want to test the assertion that a strings contains exactly 4 of those special characters, and they are all in a row, you can use the regular expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]{4}[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$`. That reads, "match the beginning of the line followed by zero or more non-special characters followed by 4 special characters followed by zero or more non-special characters followed by the end of the line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this oughta just do it:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9\s]){4,}
```

Can use it like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("abcde/-*,f€gh", @"([^a-zA-Z0-9\s]){4,}").Success); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("abcde/- *,f€gh", @"([^a-zA-Z0-9\s]){4,}").Success); // Prints False
```

Comment: Thank you, that works exactly as I wanted. Also I'm sorry for asking with little information, this is my first question in the stackoverflow.